# Showing dollar sign for Product Attribute field... and two decimal point, if possible

Tags: product-attribute, product-list, magento-1

I was able to show a product attribute `payamount` in catalog/product/list.phtml.

But how can I show it formatted with $ sign and 2 decimal point?

```
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getpayamount() , 'payamount'); ?>
</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get price format for your custom amount, you can do that by following code.

```
<?php 

    $payamount = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getpayamount() , 'payamount'); 

    echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($payamount,true,false);

?>
```

Comment: I am sorry but what about the Product Attribute field in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml.....  Can you please show me how to display payamount field with $ sign?             Thank you!!!!!                                                                                                       <td class="product-cart-info">           
          <?php $_item = $this->getItem()?><?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('payamount')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></td>
          </tr>

Comment: Use same Mage::helper('core')->currency() function.

Comment: it works... I just started learning php and Magento... and I just  figured out variable and function....